# Exception mtcokus.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, import, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm using win8 64bit , eclipse 64bit

first i have error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ..... mtcokus.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

and my solution is down jre 32bit and use it in my eclipse as jre system libary
but after that i have the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ..... mtcokus.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

I don't know how to resolve is, i have search but no answer can use
please help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

we first download depend.ext to check out the dependence of mtcokus.dll, then download the specific dll and add it to your java.library.path.
I met the bug when I ran JLDA, and I download the depent DLL.